# Aggregate % Division based on Count of Columns - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've two tables in Power BI.

Now, I'm calculating a measure based upon two columns i.e. Sum of total count of Name (in first table i.e. 56) & "Count of email" (i.e. 12) in second table. Here is the calculation done in measure:-

**%Social = DIVIDE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Email]),COUNT('Table2'[Name]))**

i.e. **%Social= 12/56**

[image]

[image]

This formula is working properly at row level. But when i remove column "email" from the table then it's not working. I want to take this value (**21.43%**) at the aggregate level in some other table.

Current out is i.e. incorrect. Correct value is 21.43% at aggregate level.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: Can you show your current final output?

Comment: @mkRabbani Sure, I've added the current final output in the above post.